# Push Notification service in server

Tags: java, windows

How to create push Notification service in server and also will work in all mobile platforms.
Is there any library available for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could well use these 3 libraries, by platform/OS:

1. `IOS` - [JavaPNS](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/)
2. `ANDROID` - [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)
3. `ANDROID_C2DM` - [Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/)

Unfortunately I havent seen anything that wraps all 3, but it's not so hard to write a simple wrapper API for the 3 different push notification services yourself.

Note that C2DM is the "old" android version, and GCM is the new one.

Also be aware that there are some differences between IOS and Adroid. For example I found with our apps that multiple push messages to Android overwrite previous ones, whereas on IOS they do not.